# How to use MongoClientOptions instead of MongoOptions?

Tags: mongodb, builder, mongo-java-driver

I am using `MongoOptions` class and its methods

`setFsync(boolean sync)`

`setJ(boolean safe)`

`setW(int val)`

`setWtimeout(int timeoutMS)`

`setSafe(boolean isSafe)`

How to achieve this using `MongoClientOptions` as `MongoOptions` is depracated in **Mongo-Java-Driver 3.0**. I came to know `MongoClientOptions` uses

> MongoClientOptions.builder()

to create a new Builder instance and then append properties.

Answer (score 4):

Use the writeConcern method on the builder, as in:

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                                               .writeConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALED)
                                               .build();
```

or

Answer (score 2):

Things are quite a bit more complicated with client version 3.6. You'll have to instantiate a [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) and use it with [MongoClientOptions.Builder](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html). Example:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcernError;

public class MongoOptionsSample
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        WriteConcern l_concern = new WriteConcern( wVal, wTimeoutMS )
                .withJournal( bool );

        MongoClientOptions l_opts =
                MongoClientOptions
                .builder()
                .writeConcern( l_concern )
                .build();

        ServerAddress l_addr = new ServerAddress( "localhost", 27017 );

        try
        (
                MongoClient l_conn = new MongoClient( l_addr, l_opts );
        )
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Fsync and safe are deprecated. See the [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below:You can set the read prefernece and write concern using object of new Mongoclient...There are list of apis are available .Please check the below format..

```
        MongoClient c =  new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost"));
        DB db = c.getDB("final");
        DBCollection animals = db.getCollection("emp");


        BasicDBObject animal = new BasicDBObject("emp", "john");
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClient().setReadPreference(preference);
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClient().setWriteConcern(concern);
```

You can add fsynk aswell..

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClient().fsync(async)
```